# Air gapped git repository replication

Tags: git

We have a team spread over two networks who will need to work on the same codebase managed via git. For the next few weeks, we will absolutely not be able to connect these networks together due to political / security conditions, so the two teams won't be able to access one singular git server. Naturally, we are thinking about two somehow replicated git servers communicating via a sneakernet. :-)

While I am aware of the overhead of code conflicts while merging - is there a possible setup (e.g. git plugins or anything) for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 2 repositories can't "talk" to each other there there is no way to sync them.
There are several things you can do to to reduce the conflicts.

1. Use bitbucket/github to share the repositories(as private repositories)
2. Generate a **[`git bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)** and send it over email. git bundle is a kind of a read-only repo
3. Same as #2 but instead of git bundle use **[`git send-email`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email)** to update the teams vi mail.

Comment: You can sure do that, simply copy and share it over usb. the problem is that if you copy the  repositories over usb it is read/write and some one can accidentally "make" changes to your usb version and the outcome will not be so good. this is what git bundle for. a read only repo so it cannot be modified (you cant push to it so no harm can be done). but again you can transfer it over USB.

Comment: you can also use drop/box/copy etc to share the repo as well. put your git repo as drop box folder and it can be shared a well.